# How do I compare two querysets in Django and filter those which don't match exactly?

Tags: python, django

I have three models, Fridge, Recipe and Ingredient and I want to get queryset of all recipes and compare their ingredients with the food contents of my fridge object. I want to filter out all of the recipes, which don't have the matching ingredients to my food contents and return the queryset only of those matching.

Fridge and Food are both in one app, Recipe and Ingredient in other.

I am pretty new to Django and I wasn't able to find a way how to do it. I only managed to filter out recipes using a search input, but that is just a single word.

```py
class Fridge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="my_fridge", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food_contents = models.ManyToManyField(Food, related_name="in_fridges")
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
    is_expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    preparation_time = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    servings = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    instructions = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name="ingredients", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: add FOOD  model as well to understand properly

Comment: Do the models need to be in 2 different apps? Otherwise you could import the app `from appname.models import Recipe` and you could get `values_list()` for the names in Food model and the Ingredient model and just compare them